# Uma dúvida com HashMap

Tags: java

Fiz um código simples para cadastrar uma pessoa em um `HashMap`. `Pessoa` é uma classe que tem nome e idade, porém não está dando para cadastrar mais de uma pessoa. Sempre que vou mostrar, ela mostra só a primeira que cadastrei.

Meu código:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            int op;
            String nome;
            int ide;
            int j = 0;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            Map<Integer,Pessoa>Mostra = new HashMap<Integer,Pessoa>();
            while(true){
                System.out.println("1-Cadastrar");
                System.out.println("2-Mostrar todas");
                op = sc.nextInt();
                if(op == 1) {
                    if(Mostra.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("Nome");
                        nome = sc.next();
                        System.out.println("idade");
                        ide = sc.nextInt();
                        Pessoa p = new Pessoa(nome,ide);
                        Mostra.put(1,p);
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Nome");
                        nome = sc.next();
                        System.out.println("idade");
                        ide = sc.nextInt();
                        Pessoa p = new Pessoa(nome,ide);
                        for(int i = 0; i < Mostra.size(); i++) {
                            j++;
                        }
                        Mostra.put(j,p);
                    }
                }else if(op == 2) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < Mostra.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println(Mostra.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Você está usando Java 7 ou superior? Se sim, pode usar o operador diamante, deixa mais elegante instanciar um `new HashMap<>()` do que um `new HashMap<Integer, Pessoa>`

Comment: E seu código não está adequado ao uso de `HashMap`, seria muito melhor com listas...

Comment: eu sei que seria melhor usar listas, porém tenho prova amanhã e não to sabendo como usar o hashmap direito

Comment: assim?  Map Mostra = new HashMap<>();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos simplificar o seu código.

Quando você tem algo assim:

```
if (x) {
    a;
    b;
    c;
    d1;
} else {
    a;
    b;
    c;
    d2;
}
```

Supondo que a avaliação de `x` não produza efeitos colaterais em `a`, `b` ou `c` ou vice-versa, você poderia simplificar esse código para ficar assim:

```
a;
b;
c;
if (x) {
    d1;
} else {
    d2;
}
```

Esse é o caso das linhas que instanciam `Pessoa`.

Como você está se preparando para uma prova, deve saber que a convenção de nomenclatura diz que nomes de variáveis deveriam ser com letra minúscula. Portanto, use `Mostra` ao invés de `mostra`.

E também temos isso daqui:

```
                    for(int i = 0; i < Mostra.size(); i++) {
                        j++;
                    }
                    Mostra.put(j,p);
```

O fato de você usar `i` no cabeçalho do `for` e `j` no corpo está errado **e esse é o erro que faz seu código não funcionar**. No entanto, usar um `for` para fazer isso por si só já está errado, pois é o equivalente a contar nos dedos quando você tem uma calculadora a sua disposição. Acho que o que você queria era simplesmente isso:

```
                   mostra.put(mostra.size() + 1, p);
```

Com essas mudanças, teremos um código assim:

```
                if (mostra.isEmpty()) {
                    mostra.put(1, p);
                } else {
                    mostra.put(mostra.size() + 1, p);
                }
```

O que aconteceria se o caso do `if` tivesse entrado no `else`? Teremos que `mostra.size()` vai dar zero, e somado com 1, vai dar 1, que é exatamente o que há no corpo do `if`. Assim sendo, podemos eliminar o `if`.

E também, já que a ideia é aprender o uso do `Map`, você pode aprender a utilizá-lo com o *enhanced-for* sem precisar de um contador para isso:

```
                for (Pessoa p : mostra.values()) {
                    System.out.println(p);
                }
```

Declarar a variável no menor escopo possível apenas quando for utilizá-la também costuma ser boa ideia.

Seu código fica assim:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Integer, Pessoa> mostra = new HashMap<>();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("1-Cadastrar");
            System.out.println("2-Mostrar todas");
            int op = sc.nextInt();
            if (op == 1) {
                System.out.println("Nome");
                String nome = sc.next();
                System.out.println("idade");
                int idade = sc.nextInt();
                Pessoa p = new Pessoa(nome, idade);
                mostra.put(mostra.size() + 1, p);
            } else if (op == 2) {
                for (Pessoa p : mostra.values()) {
                    System.out.println(p);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: muito obrigado, era isso mesmo